# append string to image src using js

Tags: javascript, append, src

I've got a page where there is `<img src="/images/product/whatever-image.jpg" alt="" />`

I want it so that upon loading of the page, the string "?Action=thumbnail" is appended to src's value, making it `src="/images/product/whatever-image.jpg?Action=thumbnail"`

how do I achieve this using js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    /* assuming only one img element */
    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    image.src += '?Action=thumbnail';
}, false);
```

Note, changing the source of the image will "re-fetch" the image from the server — even if the image is the same. This will be better done on the server-side.

---

***Update after comment:***

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    /* assuming only one div with class "divclassname" and img is first child */
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('divclassname')[0].firstChild;

    image.src += '?Action=thumbnail';
}, false);
```

Comment: how would i proceed if i wanted to get element by the div class within which the image is held?

Comment: awesome man thanks! img wasn't the first child in the div, the image was wrapped in a link tag, so i gave the link a classname, and used that instead. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myImage').src += "/Action=thumbnail";
};
```